# How to fix Python 3 Json file error in Pycharm?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to write the following code but I am getting the attached error. 
I don't know what seems to be the problem?

Have tried a lot of different ways

```
birthday = {}

with open('birthdays.json', 'r') as f:
          birthday = json.load(f)
```

and the error message I receive is the following:

```
File "/Users/Apple/PycharmProjects/test1/birthday_dictionaries2.py", line 4, in <module>
    with open('birthdays.json', 'r') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'birthdays.json'
```

Comment: You fix it by creating `/Users/Apple/PycharmProjects/test1/birthdays.json`... Please show us that file actually exists.

Comment: when I do that I get the following errors:

Comment: Creating a file shouldn't give you errors... And please [edit] your question to include additional details to the post. But you could also write `open('/Users/Apple/PycharmProjects/test1/birthdays.json', 'r')`, and you should see the same error

Answer (score 0):

May sound basic but have you included `import json` and confirmed the existence of `birthdays.json` in same directory as Python File?

Because in my PyCharm it worked well

Answer (score 0):

In Pycharm when you run a script you also have to choose the PATH in the`Run configuration menu` you want to run at. You may have changed the `Run configuration` before, try to check it.